# Abort a block with a variable and not raising?

Tags: python, with-statement

I would like a `if`, `with`, or alternative statement to not enter the block on a condition with a side effect, e.g. similar to this:

```
with sometimes_run_block() as value:
    print('this should only sometimes run', value)
```

The with statement context looks something like this:

```
@contextmanager
def sometimes_run_block():
    if random.random() > 0.5:
        yield 'hello!'
    else:
        yield
```

At the moment I am yielding nothing in my `@contextmanager` decorated function and checking if the value is not `None`. To me it seems redundant to have an extract check, causing it to be three lines and two levels of indentation:

```
with sometimes_run_block() as value:
    if value:
        print('this should only sometimes run', value)
```

Another alternative is not using a `with`:

```
value = sometimes_run_block()
if value:
    print('this should only sometimes run', value)
```

The current working two line solution is to use a `for` statement but it is misleading.

```
for value in sometimes_run_block():
    print('this should only sometimes run', value)
```

Is it possible to skip processing of a context block (as if it was an `if` statement) but without raising an exception while introducing a context variable?

Comment: that's not really what the `with` statement does or is for.. Execution branching is done with the `if` statement.

Comment: If want to get fancy you could use a decorator maybe, but for readability the if condition is preferred. Is there any reason why the desicion must be taken in a contextmanager?

Comment: @memoselyk Doesn't have to be, just having two lines doing this would be good as I inferred.

Comment: @ChadS. I've edited my question to show that I'm not only after using `with`. It can be anything that has a side effect and two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way is the best way:

```
value = sometimes_run_block()
if value:
    print('this should only sometimes run', value)
```

This is Python, after all--we tend not to chase cycles, we don't value concision over clarity.  If you want to do something wacky that's up to you, but whoever maintains your code later will hopefully figure out how to undo it before it drives them mad.

Comment: I like your answer, but it should be pointed out that he should redefine `sometimes_run_block()` to remove the `contextmanager` decorator and change his `yield` statements to `return` statements.